# When I use the Django generic view update_object

Tags: django

When I use the Django generic `update_object` view to edit, I always get this error:

```
 Page not found (404) Request Method:
 POST Request URL:
 http://127.0.0.1:8000/bookmarks/edit/
```

My `url.py`

```
(r'^edit/(?P<object_id>\d+)$',
                         update_object,
                         {'form_class':BookForm,
                          'post_save_redirect':'/',
                          'queryset':Book.objects.all()
                          }),
```

My template:

```
<form action="." method="POST">
    {{form.as_p}}
    <p>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Next?" /></button>
    </p>
</form>
```

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 2):

In your template post, the URL is: `/bookmarks/edit/`. It did not match `^edit/(?P<object_id>\d+)$`.

So edit

```
<form action="." method="POST">
```

to

```
<form action="/bookmarks/edit/{{ object.id }}" method="POST">
```

and then it will be work!

Or change the URL `^edit/(?P<object_id>\d+)$` to `^edit/(?P<object_id>\d*)$`.

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
r'^edit/(?P<object_id>\d+)$'
```